# Any homeomorphism from $[0,1)\to [0,1)$ has a fixed point.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Show that

> Any homeomorphism from $[0,1)\to [0,1)$ has a fixed point.

**My try**:

Suppose that  $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x$,then either $f(x)>x$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x$ otherwise if $f(a)>a$ and  $f(b)<b$ for some  $a,b\in [0,1)$ then by IVP $f(p)=p;p\in [a,b]\subset [0,1)$ which is false.

Hence take WLOG ; $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ ;

Also if $f^{-1}(x)>x$ then by above we have $f(f^{-1}(x))>f^{-1}(x)>x\implies x>x $ false .Hence $f^{-1}(x)\le x$ for some $x$ .

But I can't complete the proof from here.Please give some hints so that I can take it forward.

Comment: Since $0$ is the only point in $[0,1)$ that deleting won't disconnect the space, any homeomorphism must send $0$ to $0$.

Comment: Another way to see that $f(0)=0$ is that $0$ is the only point of the space that has a local base $B$ such that $\forall b\in B\; (\partial b$ contains exactly one point.)

Comment: @Learn more all your questions are basically tifr questions lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument showing that if the result fails, then either $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$ or $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$ is basically correct, but the statement of it needs a little work. You’ve considered only the possibility that $f(a)<a<b<f(b)$; it’s also possible that $f(a)>a<b>f(b)$. You could simply observe that in either case $f(x)-x$ must change sign on the interval $[a,b]$.

HINT: The result is false if $f$ need not be surjective, so I will assume that $f$ is a surjection.

- By considering $f(0)$, show that it’s impossible to have $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$.
- If $f(x)>x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$, show that $0\notin f\big[[0,1)\big]$.

Comment: Isn't the definition of homeomorphism: a continuous map with continuous inverse? And thus the bijectivity is included in the existence of an inverse?

Comment: since $f$ is a homeomorphism so it is in fact a bijection ;why assume surjection ?

Comment: @b00nheT: No. It’s entirely possible to have a homeomorphism of $X$ properly *into* $X$. For example, the map $$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\tan^{-1}x$$ is a homeomorphism of $\Bbb R$ onto the subspace $\left(-\frac{\pi}2,\frac{\pi}2\right)$. The statement that $f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism is ambiguous, since the codomain of $f$ need not be the same as the range of $f$.

Comment: @Peter: See my previous comment.

Comment: Please check the logic:if $f(x)<x$ then $f(0)<0$ false;if $f(x)>x $ then since $f$ is a surjection so there exists $a\in [0,1)$ such that $f(a)=0$ but $f(a)>a\implies 0>a$ false

Comment: @BrianM.Scott;Sir please have a look and convey

Comment: @Peter: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: thanks;it's always encouraging to solve problems with you around@BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Peter: You’re welcome (and thank you).

Comment: I had one question;We know that a metric space is compact iff every real valued continuous function is bounded.Is the result true in case of differentiable function also@BrianM.Scott

Comment: @Brian: I know that there was a time when " homeomorphism" did not imply subjectivity.  I think that time has mostly passed.  E.g. nowadays we want homeomorphisms to be the isomorphisms in the category of topological spaces.  I would be interested to learn of a text currently in print/use which allows homeomorphisms not to be surjective.

Comment: @Peter: You don’t have a notion of differentiability in arbitrary metric spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott;Should I wait for an answer or you are busy right now

Comment: @Pete: I expect that it’s at least the default understanding nowadays, but on the other hand I would not expect a randomly chosen set-theoretic topologist to care much more than I do about category-theoretic notions, and I’ve never found them at all useful.

Comment: @Peter: Expanding on my previous comment: in order for the question to be meaningful, you need a space for which the notion of *differentiable function* makes sense. I don’t whether it’s always true that if $X$ is such a space, and every differentiable real-valued function on $X$ is bounded, then $X$ is compact, though I shouldn’t be at all surprised.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I_1$ and $I_2$ be intervals on the real line.  Let $f$ be a homeomorphism between them.

1. Use IVP (the Intermediate Value Property) to show that $f$ is either increasing or decreasing.
2. Deduce that $f$ takes endpoints of $I_1$ to endpoints of $I_2$.
3. Conclude that if $I_1 = I_2 = [0,1)$, then...

Comment: Pete: I saw your profile page coming from a Hot network post in Academia. Regarding the broken links in your answers, you may consider checking this question: [Is there any support for mass link editing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237110/209901). You being a very valuable user, I suspect the issue could be handled by the [se] staff.

Comment: What does IVP abbreviation?

Comment: suppose $f$ is increasing then clearly $0\mapsto 0$. So there is a fixed point. But if $f$ is decreasing how can I get a fixed point?

Comment: @Epsilon: by 2., $f$ takes endpoints to endpoints.  Since the intervals have only one endpoint, $f$ cannot be decreasing.